# Android splash screen app gererate 2 APK files

Tags: android

Below  xml is used to make a splash screen in Android. I have tested and is working fine. But when I generate APK file and install it will install 2 apps? 
One is with splash screen and another one is without splash screen.Why? Sorry, I'm new in Android and just follow the tutorial.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Label tag should only use with application tag,

```
  android:label="@string/app_name"
```

**So remove this label tag from:**

```
<!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" //remove this
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" //remove this >
    </activity>
```